# where is the 301 redirect coming from?

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, http-status-code-301

Tearing my hair out here.

Developing a web site on my local machine at dev.thingy.com. (ASP.NET/IIS7).

Somehow whenever an ASPX page is called, it redirects with a 301 to local.thingy.com.

I realize I must at some point have set this up but I cannot find where. I have checked and it is NOT any of the following places:

- In IIS web site settings
- In IIS redirection setting
- In URL rewriting settings in web.config
- In my hosts file
- In my error page settings in IIS

This only happens with ASPX pages, not standard HTML pages which do not redirect.

So where on earth is this 301 redirect coming from?

Comment: Log in or other security settings?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 0):

301 I think is from the browser cache. DId you try clearing the browser cache?